# Show image dimensions in status bar in Windows 8 File Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8

When I'm dealing with image files in Windows Explorer (aka File Explorer in Windows 8) I want to see the image dimensions in pixels (i.e. 400px x 300px) in the status bar. This has worked fine in Windows 7 but in Windows 8 it's not there anymore. It only shows the number of selected items and the file size.

How can I enable image dimensions in File Explorer status bar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the "Dimensions" column to explorer to get those details, once you add the columns you want, save the folder properies to make it add "Dimensions" to all folders like the one you have open.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is actually very helpful and is pretty close in terms of comfortability.

Comment: how do u save the folder properies ?

Comment: Nice trick, but you have to do that for all folders with images.

Answer (score 7):

I also searched around a little bit about that topic because it was a quite useful feature.

Unfortunately, the only way I found to get those details is by enabling the details pane (in explorer --> view --> click on details pane).

However, this view is panned on the right side of the explorer ((I did not manage to move it) and uses much more space than the old one in status bar. It's quite annoying, but you can quickly enable/disable this pane if you right-click on the details pane toggle --> add to tool bar for quick access (or something like that, I do not have the English version). Then the toggle shows up at the top window border.

Hope this helps you a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've already found this as well but as you said - it takes too much real estate in my window.

Comment: @FleshWound Thanks for the tip on how to place Details Pane toggle into the Quick access toolbar. Apparently, there is a keyboard shortcut for this toggle: Alt+Shift+P

Answer (score 3):

I used this feature a lot in Windows 7 as well and missed it upon switching to Windows 8. The "Content" view shows both the thumbnail and image size in the same view which is most helpful to me since image names aren't always descriptive.

[image]

Comment: you can edit the answer to include a URL pointing to the pic you upload to another website :)

Comment: Nice one, easier than to add "dimensions"

Comment: Thank you. Although it was in front of me but I didn't realize this would be so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Classicshell](http://www.classicshell.net) would let you do this

I've tested this with ClassicShell 4.3.1. You will need the "Classic Explorer" option enabled when installing. Once done, you need to close any file manager type windows open (like the default file explorer), open file explorer (so the classic shell file explorer opens) and you will be able to see the dimensions of  any image,